# Unable to retrieve all the records from snowflake using snowflake-jdbc driver. but issue is not exists in snowflake browser

Tags: jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, resultset

i was trying to compare sql server and snowflake result sets using respective jdbc connectors.
But snowflake results was not giving all records if records count greater than 3+ lacks. missing lot many records.

Ex:i am executing scripts for date range (2000-01-01 to 2020-12-31) and internally query is executing day by day. for some random days snowflake results set count and sql server results set counts are not matching.

Note: Data is available in snowflake but while retrieving through snowflake-jdbc connector, it is not fetching all the records

SnowFlake version:5.33.1
SnowFlake-JDBC connector version-3.13.6

sample code:

```
public static int countsnowfalkeVar=0;
public static int countsqlVar=0;
ResultsSet SqlSet=Select * from sqlServequery
ResultsSet SnowflakeSet=Select * from snowflakeQuery
while(SnowflakeSet.next())
{
for (int columnCount = 1; columnCount <= numberOfColumns1; columnCount++) {
snowFlakeal.add(SnowflakeSet.getString(columnCount));
}
countsnowfalkeVar++;
}
while(SqlSet.next())
{
for (int columnCount = 1; columnCount <= numberOfColumns1; columnCount++) {
snowFlakeal.add(SqlSet.getString(columnCount));
}
countsqlVar++;
}

o/p: countsqlVar=   440687
    countsnowfalkeVar=418259
```

Comment: There isn't enough information provided to be able to comment on. First, an example of the scripts you are using would be useful, and secondly have you enabled JDBC logging and if yes, have you checked the logs? To enable JDBC logging follow this [article](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors#JDBC)

Comment: @sergiu, added sample code for more details

Comment: Are you sure the SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <table> on Snowflake UI returns a different value? And is the table being changed or not?

Comment: @sergiu, yes. if we perform Select count(*) from <table> on snowflake UI getting different value and correct value. Data exists in snowflake. For some random dates, not fetching all records using snowflake-JDBC driver

Comment: Enable JDBC logging with *tracing=all* and see if any errors/warnings are reported there.

Comment: @Bhavanikandi So what was it?